# How can I post form data to a url without a trailing slash? iis6, asp classic or .net

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, iis-6

I am working on a fairly simple API where a 3rd party makes a post to my server and I reply with data. However, I am hitting a brick wall with one of their requirements:

"All the URLs in the API below do not use a trailing slash and you cannot redirect to a URL that contains one."

Combined with:

"Requests are sent by adding "/api_name" to your endpoint and sending the params explained below in a POST request."

If I don't have a trailing slash, I receive a "HTTP Error 405 - The HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed. Internet Information Services (IIS)" error since you cannot post to a directory.

I have been searching all day for a resolution and have come up with nothing. I cannot be the only one with this issue.

This is on a windows 2003 server so I would prefer to stick with either asp classic or .net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link to a site that details how to add a handler mapping:

[add fast CGI handler to IIS](http://www.activeservers.com/Script_Maps.aspx)

You can follow those steps to set .NET as the handler to any extension. So, if it is possible to set your "api_name" to something like "myservice.api" and then you add ".api" as an extension for the .NET ISAPI handler, then you should be able to route their calls to your service. If you cannot change your "api_name" in their system to something with a period in it (which, really you could set "api_name" to "myservice.asmx" if you wanted to) then you will have to try to wrangle with extensionless URL's in IIS 6. This takes a little more work from what I recall:

[.NET extensionless URLs as they are needed for .NET MVC 3 on IIS 6](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/12/22/asp-net-mvc-3-extensionless-urls-on-iis-6.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely look into this further today. Unfortunately the "/app_name" is exactly that and unchangeable on my end. I can define what comes before it, but that is the only control I have. So I can either have "www.mycompany.com/apis/app_name" or "www.mycompany.com/apis/myservice.api/app_name"

Comment: (Double post since I cannot seem to edit the one from 4 hours ago) Apparently .net doesn't have an issue with "default.aspx/app_name" and is receiving the parameters just fine! I guess I didn't try it Friday, I swear I tried everything else :p

Comment: Happy it worked out for you. As an aside, upgrading to IIS 7.5 will allow you to do this with much less effort in the future.